# PHP : type declaration for class properties failed

Tags: types, php-7.4

I'm using type declaration for class properties (member variables)

```
class MyClass
{
    private int $_myInt=0;
    ...
}
```

I got on server#1 :

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in ...`

Every thing goes smooth on server#2.
Both servers (linux) run php 7.4.33

The error disappears if I remove the type declaration.

How could it be explained ? Is there a config issue ? Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Just `private $_myInt=0;` ?

Comment: @tilz0R `private  $_myInt=0;` works fine but I would like to declare the type to ensure that the value is of the correct and specified type